# How to solve this NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I followed all the different solutions (or I think I did) on Github(https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/360#issuecomment-55697207) and other similar posts on stackoverflow, but still could not get it working. I still see the NoMethodError. My repo is a really basic practice website. 
Please help at 
https://github.com/lukexuanliu/CornellBlog/tree/static_pages
Thanks!

rails 4.1.5
rspec 3.1.3

bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
F

Failures:

1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'PRACTICE RAILS'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages::HomePage:0x007fe3f40681c0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.00051 seconds (files took 0.14214 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'PRACTICE RAILS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding require 'rails_helper' as you are using the newer version.

In old versions, single file was generated which was spec_helper.rb. Now the details in this file 
have been moved to rails_helper.rb. The new spec_helper.rb is just a helper.

Comment: I added the require 'rails_helper' to my spec file. and config.include Capybara::DSL to my rails_helper.rb. It finally works with a deprecation warning. This was such a setback at a newer version of rspec...